# Creating custom Error classes from C++ code in V8

Tags: javascript, c++, error-handling, v8

I want to create custom exceptions in a native NodeJS (0.11.5) extension. I'm trying to create subclasses of the builtin `Error` class in V8 (3.20.11).

Basically I'm looking for a C++ equivalent of the following Javascript code:

```
function MyError(message) {
  Error.apply(this, arguments);
  this.message = message;
}
MyError.prototype = new Error;
MyError.prototype.name = MyError.name;

new MyError("message")
```

I tried digging in the V8 source and I found the following helper method that appears to do part of what I want:

```
Handle<Object> Factory::NewError(const char* constructor,
                                 Handle<String> message)
```

Unfortunately it looks like it's a private API and I don't understand enough V8 to figure out how to construct something similar myself. It would be great to be able to write a method that I could use in a similar way as creating a built-in `Error` instance, for example:

```
ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8::String::New(msg)))
// becomes...
ThrowException(MyError(v8::String::New(msg)))
```

I'm looking for a solution that is as close as possible to a subclass of the builtin `Error` class. It should probably satisfy the following:

```
var e = new MyError("message");
assert(e instanceof MyError);
assert(e instanceof Error);
assert(e.name === "MyError");
assert(e.message === "message");
```

Any suggestions where to start?

Comment: Why not do this in Javascript?

Comment: The exceptions need to be accessible from the C++ code so they can be thrown from the C++ code. A solution that uses exceptions written in JS is acceptable I guess (although I don't know how to do that), but I feel it's not really a concern of the JS code to provide exceptions to the C++ extension.

Comment: An extension should just do the bare minimum that was not possible to do from js and all the high level stuff should be in the js part which calls it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about NodeJS, but one possibility might be to throw whatever C++ exception makes sense, catch it at the extension boundary, use standard V8 calls to construct the appropriate JavaScript exception, and call `v8::ThrowException()`. This approach may not be an option if NodeJS doesn't give your extension direct access to V8.

Here's a sample program that shows how to set up the custom error class and instantiate it from C++. Hopefully NodeJS gives you enough V8 access to do something similar:

```
#include "v8.h"
#include <iostream>

static void Print(v8::Handle<v8::Value> value)
{
    std::cout << *v8::String::Utf8Value(value) << std::endl;
}

static v8::Local<v8::Value> RunScript(const char* code)
{
    return v8::Script::Compile(v8::String::New(code))->Run();
}

static void RunTest(v8::Isolate* isolate)
{
    // setup
    v8::Locker locker(isolate);
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolateScope(isolate);
    v8::HandleScope handleScope(isolate);
    auto context = v8::Context::New(isolate);
    v8::Context::Scope contextScope(context);

    // create custom error class/function
    auto code =
        "function MyError(message) {"
            "Error.apply(this, arguments);"
            "this.message = message;"
        "}"
        "MyError.prototype = new Error;"
        "MyError.prototype.name = MyError.name;"
        "MyError";
    auto errorFunc = RunScript(code)->ToObject();

    // create custom error instance
    auto message = v8::String::New("message");
    v8::Handle<v8::Value> args[] = { message };
    auto error = errorFunc->CallAsConstructor(1, args);

    // validate custom error instance
    context->Global()->Set(v8::String::New("e"), error);
    Print(RunScript("e instanceof MyError"));
    Print(RunScript("e instanceof Error"));
    Print(RunScript("e.name === 'MyError'"));
    Print(RunScript("e.message === 'message'"));
}

void main(void)
{
    auto isolate = v8::Isolate::New();
    RunTest(isolate);
    isolate->Dispose();
}
```

Comment: NodeJS is not really the issue I think. The problem is I am having trouble constructing JavaScript exceptions in V8 that are of a different (sub)type than the standard ones (Error, TypeError, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
class Error
{
    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    virtual ~Error() throw() {};

    protected:
    Error(std::exception& exception)
    :   m_exception(&exception)
    {}

    // Element Access
    // ==============

    public:
    const char* msg() const { return m_exception->what(); }

    // Message
    // =======

    protected:
    static std::string message(const std::string& msg, const std::string& context);

    static std::string message(const std::string& msg) {
        return message(msg, "");
    }

    // Cast
    // ====

    protected:
    template <typename Derived>
    static std::exception& cast(Derived& derived) {
        return static_cast<std::exception&>(derived);
    }

    private:
    std::exception* m_exception;
};



class ErrorLogic : public std::logic_error, public Error
{
    public:
    static std::string info();

    ErrorLogic()
    :   std::logic_error(message(info())), Error(cast(*this))
    {}

    explicit ErrorLogic(const std::string& msg)
    :   std::logic_error(message(msg)), Error(cast(*this))
    {}

    template <typename T>
    ErrorLogic(const std::string& msg, const T& context)
    :   std::logic_error(message(msg, context)), Error(cast(*this))
    {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't look like this is exposed to the Javascript runtime at all. I'm looking for a solution where the C++ V8 extension raises an error that can be caught and handled by the calling Javascript code.

Comment: V8 uses a subset of C++ that doesn't incorporate c++ exceptions.